# Narrow a type to the exhaustive type union of its values without const assertion

Tags: typescript

### Problem

With this code [*(TypeScript Playground Link)*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUh1BLALgCwPYFdGQMaoHYDOWAhgQQKYBOi8+UIw4uhWB6ARgFbnZYC8kANpRIogN4jRUyACIAZvHIAbACYyAXLKKV4eAOYB9AIwyANJMgBfc9InTp8xao1bEO-QYBMZi9fABdAG5wcEQATwAHckgAZQ5uXkgBcKjUOUg2Lh5EQTx0AFt2KiDwIA) :

```
/**
 * Without const assertion
 */
const subject = [
    {
        "field": "string_1",
    },
    {
        "field": "string_2",
    },
];

type Subject = typeof subject[number];
```

> ```
> type Subject = {
>     field: string;
> }
> ```

So I have to use const assertion to narrow the `Subject` type to the exhaustive type union of its values

Here is the code [*(TypeScript Playground Link)*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUh1BLALgC0gYwPYDsDOjICGOOApgE6LzZQjDia744CuARgFYlr4C8kA2lEjCA3kOETIAIgBm8EgBsAJlIBc0vGXhYA5gH0AjFIA04yAF9TksZMmz5ytRsRbdegEwmzl8AF1COOjYeADc4OCIAJ4ADiSQAMpsnNyQfFGxGDKQLBxciPxYzAC2rOS+YUA) :

```
/**
 * With const assertion
 */
const subject = [
    {
        "field": "string_1",
    },
    {
        "field": "string_2",
    },
] as const;

type Subject = typeof subject[number];
```

> ```
> type Subject = {
>     readonly field: "string_1";
> } | {
>     readonly field: "string_2";
> }
> ```

But in my use-case, I cannot do const assertion on `subject` (because i'm importing it from a library).
So how to achieve that result?

### Tries

I tried this code [*(TypeScript Playground Link)*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUh1BLALgCwPYFdGQMaoHYDOWAhgQQKYBOi8+UIw4uhWB6ARgFbnZYC8kANrgAkAG9RIgEQAzeOQA2AEykAuSFKKV4eAOYB9AIxSANKIC+Z8ZNnzlajVp0GATKYtmAugG5w4UBDQkACCkADkzERhkKQU1LSEOMR4kPgKAJ6Q7OQxAA65CvJKkIiokJTkMlTkeNjkBCVlNegAtpAt5C3ZlAQmqZSQTnp9eK3dfeyoqArkyX3ElJTE6X2oA6hcPFiFiFTECgQAdPSMkawc3LwAwvhEkAJsm7yCo11UnoK2iiqeMQ1nvnAiHSuRyAGULlsbix7iUQeRUDJBpDrrdEL4gA)

```
/**
 * Without const assertion
 */
const subject = [
    {
        "field": "string_1",
    },
    {
        "field": "string_2",
    },
];

/**
 * Error: A 'const' assertions can only be applied to references to enum members, or string, number, boolean, array, or object literals.
 */
const subjectConst = subject[number]["field"] as const;

type SubjectConst = typeof subjectConst;
```

But

> Error: A 'const' assertions can only be applied to references to enum members, or string, number, boolean, array, or object literals.(1355)

Comment: Is the list of values going to change much?  I'd be tempted to have a function that converts those values to another type, one that you have control over, and throws on anything unsupported — e.g. the library being updated and the list changing.  Depends on how much you need to pass these values back into said library, but isolating these things can help in some situations

Comment: @SamMason the values are going to change much, yes; hard coding the types would be too tedious.

Comment: Types define static properties of code, by definition they are hard coded as static properties define invariants.  Maybe you mean you don't want to write them all by hand?  In that case a `sed` script (or similar) might be suitable for pulling the relevant values out of the library before compiling.

Comment: @SamMason yes, I meant copy all of the values by hand to make the type. I'm not familiar about `sed` scripts. Wouldn't there be no solution built-in typescript for that use-case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot affect how `subject` is defined or declared, then it is unfortunately too late and what you want is impossible.  The type of `subject` is `{ field: string }[]`, and you cannot derive the string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"string_1"` or `"string_2"` from it.

The information you need is simply not present; it was thrown away by the default inference behavior whereby `string`-valued properties are widened to `string`.  The time to change that is at the declaration site for `subject`, such as using a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on the initializing array literal.  You can't make that decision later on.  Using a `const` assertion later is as useless as buckling your seatbelt *after* a car accident.

You may be able to derive the information you care about from the library in some other way, such as parsing the files yourself, but TypeScript alone cannot do it for you.